# Using clang or gcc, how do I list the templates instantiated in an object file (.o)?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang

I have a large program that's generating object files that are much larger than I expect.  My suspicion is that somewhere in the program, someone is using inefficient template metaprogramming that's generating O(n**2) template types.  Is there a command-line tool that I can use to list all of the template types that exist in an object file (.o)?

Normally I would suspect `nm` or `objdump` is the right tool for this kind of thing, but it's not obvious to me what flags to pass to list the template types.

I've verified that the information is in the .o file using this simple test program:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
    struct foo : public foo<Ts...> {};

template <>
    struct foo<int> {};

void bar() {
  foo<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int> x;
}
```

Then running:

```
gcc -g -c test.cc -o test.o && strings test.o
```

Outputs:

```
foo<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int>
GNU C++17 13.2.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -fasynchronous-unwind-tables
_Z3barv
foo<int, int, int, int, int, int, int>
foo<int, int, int, int>
foo<int, int, int, int, int, int>
foo<int, int, int>
foo<int>
foo<int, int>
foo<int, int, int, int, int>
/tmp
test.cc
/tmp
test.cc
test.cc
GCC: (Debian 13.2.0-10) 13.2.0
test.cc
_Z3barv
.symtab
.strtab
.shstrtab
.text
.data
.bss
.rela.debug_info
.debug_abbrev
.rela.debug_aranges
.rela.debug_line
.debug_str
.debug_line_str
.comment
.note.GNU-stack
.rela.eh_frame
```

I'm looking for a command that will output `foo<int>`, `foo<int, int>`, etc. from test.o.

Comment: I would probably start with something like `nm --defined-only foo.o | c++filt` and see what I get. Maybe I'd `grep` through the output. I wouldn't expect an option like `--template-types` to exist. Also, things might get inlined...

Comment: I don't think `gcc -g -c test.c -o test.o && strings test.o`
can be correct, since you can't compile C++ source from a `.c` source file with `gcc`,
(not without `-x c++`).

Comment: @MikeKinghan Yes, that was a typo.  Fixed to test.cc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous, now deleted, answer I kicked off with:

> By the time you've got to an object file, classes have no representation,
> therefore classes that instantiate templates have no representation

To which you commented:

> Re: "classes that instantiate templates have no representation". I made a simple test.cc
> file that instantiates many template classes that have no methods or members. If I compile
> it with debugging information and run strings test.o, I can see the names of the instantiated
> templates in the object file. They're definitely in there.

Which is so. I should have chosen my words more carefully. Classes have no linkage representation.
But that's quite immaterial if you can readily make an object file containing the strings your're looking
for. The strings you are seeing are DWARF debugging info, which GCC by default packages into the
object the file (or optionally with a separate `.dwo` file). I didn't consider getting the debug info, but indeed it is - or it contains -
the information you want.

Naturally you can get at the debug info in a straightforwardly structured format unpolluted with whatever other strings the
object file might contain. If I compile my previous `example.cpp` like so:

```
$ g++ -g -ggnu-pubnames -c example.cpp
```

then the compiler is instructed ([GCC manual: 3.10 Options for Debugging Your Program](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html)):

> -ggnu-pubnames
>
> Generate .debug_pubnames and .debug_pubtypes sections in a format suitable
> for conversion into a GDB index. This option is only useful with a linker that can produce GDB index version 7.

Then, the `.debug_pubtypes` section will itemise every type that is used in the object file, and they can be
specifically extracted with:

```
$ readelf --debug-dump=pubtypes example.o | c++filt
Contents of the .debug_gnu_pubtypes section:

  Length:                              1670
  Version:                             2
  Offset into .debug_info section:     0
  Size of area in .debug_info section: 4479

    Offset  Kind          Name
    37      g,type        std::integral_constant<bool, true>
    be9     s,type        bool
    37      g,type        std::integral_constant<bool, true>
    b2      g,type        std::integral_constant<bool, false>
    b2      g,type        std::integral_constant<bool, false>
    12d     g,type        std::integral_constant<long unsigned int, 0>
    c0b     s,type        long unsigned int
    12d     g,type        std::integral_constant<long unsigned int, 0>
    c21     s,type        unsigned char
    c28     s,type        short unsigned int
    c2f     s,type        unsigned int
    c36     s,type        long long unsigned int
    c42     s,type        __int128 unsigned
    1a8     g,type        std::__make_unsigned_selector_base
    1a8     g,type        std::__make_unsigned_selector_base
    264     s,type        std::size_t
    c65     s,type        signed char
    c6c     s,type        short int
    c73     s,type        int
    c7f     s,type        long int
    c86     s,type        long long int
    c8d     s,type        __int128
    c94     s,type        wchar_t
    c9b     s,type        char16_t
    ca2     s,type        char32_t
    284     g,type        std::__is_memcmp_ordered_with<std::byte, std::byte, true>
    284     g,type        std::__is_memcmp_ordered_with<std::byte, std::byte, true>
    d6e     s,type        long double
    d75     s,type        double
    d7c     s,type        float
    2b8     g,type        std::in_place_t
    2b8     g,type        std::in_place_t
    2f3     g,type        std::piecewise_construct_t
    2f3     g,type        std::piecewise_construct_t
    32e     g,type        std::integral_constant<long unsigned int, 2>
    32e     g,type        std::integral_constant<long unsigned int, 2>
    cc3     g,type        __gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<long long unsigned int>
    cc3     g,type        __gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<long long unsigned int>
    d07     g,type        __gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<long unsigned int>
    d07     g,type        __gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<long unsigned int>
    d3c     g,type        __gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<unsigned int>
    d3c     g,type        __gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<unsigned int>
    3b1     g,type        std::__array_traits<int, 2>
    3b1     g,type        std::__array_traits<int, 2>
    3de     g,type        std::array<int, 2>
    3de     g,type        std::array<int, 2>
    de9     g,type        point<int, 2>
    7c5     g,type        std::__array_traits<double, 3>
    7c5     g,type        std::__array_traits<double, 3>
    7f2     g,type        std::array<double, 3>
    7f2     g,type        std::array<double, 3>
    ee3     g,type        point<double, 3>
    1177    s,type        char
```

This appears to be exactly what you need, and I am wiser than I was :)

Comment: This is much more helpful.  Thank you!  Why is `-ggnu-pubnames` necessary if I can already see the strings (via `strings`) when I compile with `-g` (but without `-ggnu-pubnames`)?  Is there a way to extract the strings without needing `-ggnu-pubnames`?

Comment: I think not. Evidence won't fit in a comment but I can see using
my `example.cpp` that unless expressly asked to, in addition to `-g`, the compiler does not necessarily articulate actually used typenames in any debug section, unless
as namespace qualifiers of functions actually called or objects referenced. Further
more the `strings` output may contain false-positives - apparent template
instantiation class types at global scope that don't actually exist there.

Comment: Incidently I've noticed that `-ggnu-pubnames` is slightly supererogatory for your purpose. `-gpubnames`
is just as good, i.e the output of `readelf --debug-dump=pubtypes` will
be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using `nm` is one way to do this.

the `-C` flag will give a readable output that shows templates rather than the mangled names:

`nm -C myfile.o`

example output:

```
myfile.o:
0000000000000000 U Box<int>::func(int)
...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's a method of a instantiated template class, not the instantiated template itself.  Template metaprogramming often instantiates classes that have no methods or member variables.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if a class has no members or methods then it will not be included in the compiled binary.

Comment: Mike Kinghan's answer has more info and explains this.